# Not all code paths return a value while I return something

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I return a nickname below, but Visual Studio keeps giving me the error: Not all code paths return a value.

What am I doing wrong? I am returning a nickname... Anyone who can help me further? Couldn't find a solution on Google though...

```
    public string GetEigenaarBlog(int gebruikerid)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT NICKNAME FROM GEBRUIKER WHERE GEBRUIKERID = :GEBRUIKERID";
            command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":GEBRUIKERID", gebruikerid));
            string nickname = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteReader());
            return nickname;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need some return statement in `catch` block too. Or just throw exception in `catch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the exception handling bit, nothing's returned. Here's a fix.

```
public string GetEigenaarBlog(int gebruikerid)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT NICKNAME FROM GEBRUIKER WHERE GEBRUIKERID = :GEBRUIKERID";
        command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":GEBRUIKERID", gebruikerid));
        string nickname = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteReader());
        return nickname;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null; 
        //if you want to let the code know too put "throw;" here instead.
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: :O didn't know that I need to return something in the exception! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @xVizzi If you passed the exception to the caller, you wouldn't have to return anything. But you are swallowing the exception and the caller will be unaware of it, so you must return something.

Comment: This is very bad practice. Don't swallow the exception just to print it, rethrow it.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis , The OP doesn't print the exception. It is shown in a message box to the user. If this is good or not, greatly depends on the context - what does the application does, who uses it etc...

Comment: @omerschleifer Yes, whether it's good or not greatly depends on the context. Here we have a database retrieval function that swallows all kinds of exceptions. *It is* very bad in this context.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis , it is not swallowed but shown to the user. if, for instnace, the user is a developer and this is utility tool , what's wrong with this?

Comment: @omerschleifer What's wrong with this is that it doesn't inform the upper level of the code about what happened, only the user. It is bad practice. Yes, sometimes applying a bad kind of practice can be a valid (or the only) solution in a very specific domain. But this is obviously a beginner question and we shouldn't encourage beginners to adopt bad practices for the 1% of cases where they are valid.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis So because the OP wants something a specific way means that I get a downvote? wtf

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance `throw` instead of `return null` solves the OP's requirement of printing the exception and it does so without swallowing it. The OP doesn't demand (in the premises of the question) that the exception be swallowed.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis If you read my post again I added a comment in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
 public string GetEigenaarBlog(int gebruikerid)
            {
          string nickname = null;
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    string sql = "SELECT NICKNAME FROM GEBRUIKER WHERE GEBRUIKERID = :GEBRUIKERID";
                    command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":GEBRUIKERID", gebruikerid));
                    nickname = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteReader());           
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();                   
                }
     return nickname;

            }
```

Comment: No , it won't. I've tried it. I think it's better to have a return statement in one place at the end of the method, not scattered throughout its body.

Comment: @omerschleifer "Single exit point" vs "multiple exit points" is a matter of style/preference/holywar.

Comment: @GSerg  , hence the words "I think" start the sentence :)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared method of type string, but if you will get an exception in one of the following lines:

```
connection.Open();
string sql = "SELECT NICKNAME FROM GEBRUIKER WHERE GEBRUIKERID = :GEBRUIKERID";
command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":GEBRUIKERID", gebruikerid));
string nickname = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteReader());
```

you won't return anything because there will be jump to catch clause where you don't have a return statement.

The best practice (IMO) would be placing the return statement outside of `try..catch..finally` block and declaring returned variable at the beginning of the method (and initializing it with some default value)